# Add library path to jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, path, jar

I have an external library with dll files, I'm using netbeans and java. I would like to add a library path like: "java -Djava.library.path="bin"", to my jar file, how can i do this?
I have to add the relative path, and i do have to add it, becouse it will be a program for users and I want it to not require install at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the full JAR path:

```
java -Djava.library.path="bin/my.jar"
```

Comment: I don't think you can load DLLs from a jar this way.

Comment: Ugh, I misinterpreted the phrase _"...library path like: ... to my jar file..."_, sorry.

Comment: I think the OP wants code in his JAR file to have to find DLLs from a particular directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an absolute path for your DLLs. You don't need to change the path if you know where the library should be loaded from.

```
System.load("C:/my/path/to/dll/my.dll");
```

Comment: I get erros like: 
-UnsatisfiedLinkError: Directory separator should not appear in library name: C:\Users\Judit\Desktop\jogl-1.1.1-windows-amd64\lib\jogl_cg.dll

Comment: and :
no C:/Users/Judit/Desktop/jogl-1.1.1-windows-amd64/lib/jogl.dll in java.library.path

Comment: System.load("C:/Users/Judit/Desktop/jogl-1.1.1-windows-amd64/lib/jogl_cg.dll");

Comment: i've tried this, tried without the dll so just to lib, than tried with \\ instead of /, still don't work, i get the error:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Judit\Desktop\jogl-1.1.1-windows-amd64\lib\jogl_cg.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Comment: This means it can find this dll, but it can't find the dlls this need to load.  You may have to load() these first.

Comment: It's getting really weird now, when i call it for jogl.dll no error, when i call for jogl_cg.dll then i get error

Comment: I guess jogl_cg needs a DLL when jogl has all the libraries its needs.

Comment: I just can't get it work, is there an option to add the lib path to the jar? It works with -Djava.library.path="bin", from cmd.

Comment: You can add to the class path. What I do is copy the files to a directory which is in the library path, but that's cheating. ;)

Comment: yeah but I don't know where the user's lib folder is, and I still going to require acces to copy into it